# A parenting line that shouldn't be there shows up when connecting object to bone

Tags: animation, rigging

So I started with blender really recently and I rigged my first character on my own (when I followed tutorials this never happened).
But for some reason, it's full of parenting lines and I have no clue why that is.

Is it just my hierarchy being a mess, or what could I do to fix this?

[image]

Comment: If they are just disturbing you can disable them in display settings by pressing 'N' or by checking the buttons on upper left side, it is tough to tell why they are there just by seeing an image, it will be helpful if you add a blend file.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll look into it! :)